# MVC3 EF Ninject Generic Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ninject

I'm working on a generic repository using Entity Framework/MVC3/Ninject.MVC3.  The interface looks like this.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Query { get; }
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Edit(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}
```

My Concrete implementation looks like this.

```
    public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<T> Query
    {
        get { return context.Set<T>().AsQueryable(); }
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Edit(T entity)
    {
        context.Entry<T>(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);            
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Ninject has the binding

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(EFRepository<>));
```

What I need to do is get the last insert ID in the concrete implementation.  I have a transaction table that will get an insert based on the last table and insert ID.  I could call the transaction from the controller, but I'd rather just get it all done in the Data Access Layer, so I can easily write the transaction after the last insert/update.

First, is the above example the proper way to implement the generic repository.  Second is there a way to get the data I want through this method?

Answer (score 0):

When you call Add on an entity, and the table has an identity column (auto increment) then you can just check the entity after the SaveChanges() and it will contain the generated ID.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how I'd get that from the EFRepository class?  From the controller I can reference int id = myObject.PrimaryKey, but how do I get the conext from the generic repository directly.

Comment: @Jeff - you don't.  That's the point of a repository, you don't know how it operates.  You don't need to get the context from repository, you just check the object you added for it's ID.

Comment: Ok, I'm just looking for the easiest way to insert data into a transaction table about the last insert or update. I need to know the table name and last primary key. I was hoping this could be extracted this way to easily trigger the transaction update once the save is done.

Comment: @Jeff - I guess i don't really understand what your problem is.  You create an entity, you add it to the repository, you save changes, you look at the ID of the entity and get the ID that was inserted.  It's very simple.

Comment: How do I get the ID?  The ID column is tableNameID.  The question was how can I get that directly in the Repository.

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

So in that function I was looking to get entity.LastInsertID

Comment: @Jeff - and I told you, you don't need to get it from the repository.  Just Follow my instructions.  1) create a new instance of the entity, 2) fill out the data for the entity, 3) call Repository.Add() with your entity, 4) check entities Primary key, for the inserted identity key value.